# Playing HTML sounds repeatedly on mobile has weird behavior

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a js program that makes sounds play repeatedly via a timer and works perfectly fine on my computer, however, it does not work when I try to use it on my phone(iPhone 13) or tablet(iPad air 4). The sound is either late or does not play at all. If it provides any clues, I've also noticed that if I change the phone's system volume(with the physical buttons on the side of the phone) while the program is running, the volume bar lags and jumps instead of smoothly increasing or decreasing.

Setup to allow sounds to play on ios(since they need user interaction)

```
var click1 = new Audio('../audio/click1.mp3');
click1.preload = "auto";

enterBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //...code

    click1.volume = 0;
    click1.play();
    click1.pause();
    click1.currentTime = 0;
    click1.volume = 1;
});
```

The code that runs when it is called by a timer

```
function playClick() {
    click1.load();
    click1.play();
    click1.currentTime = 0;
    //...code
}
```

Timer code that I took from stack overflow

```
function Timer(callback, timeInterval, options) {
   this.timeInterval = timeInterval;
   
   this.start = () => {
     this.expected = Date.now() + this.timeInterval;
     this.theTimeout = null;

     if (options.immediate) {
       callback();
     }

     this.timeout = setTimeout(this.round, this.timeInterval);
     console.log('Timer Started');
   }
  this.stop = () => {
  clearTimeout(this.timeout);
  }
  this.round = () => {
    var drift = Date.now() - this.expected;
    if (drift > this.timeInterval) {
      if (options.errorCallback) {
        options.errorCallback();
      }
    }
    callback();
    this.expected += this.timeInterval;
    this.timeout = setTimeout(this.round, Math.max(0,this.timeInterval - drift));
  }
}

export default Timer;
```

Comment: Is `click1.load()` every time a good idea? And if the only purpose is to "reset" the audio starting position - would `click1.currentTime = 0` not be enough, if you did it _before_ you called `play`?

Answer (score 0):

What about using `setInterval` instead of a Timer?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Comment: set interval has some timing issues. I also don't see how that would fix the mobile audio